# How to install cocos3d? Something is wrong

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I have done and followed many tutorials on the internet to install cocos2d, and in Terminal it said that the installation was complete/successful. But then there were no Xcode templates on cocos3d? Can someone please help :)

Comment: have you closed xcode during install, and then reopened?

Comment: I thought that might be the case but then i made sure Xcode was not running and again re-installed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i re-read your question, and now I understand.

You have installed cocos2d, so there will be no templates for 3d, just 2d.  To get 3d to show up, you have to install the cocos3d extension:

http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/

Comment: But when I run the IOS cocos3d it gives me an error at "format_ = pvr.format;"

Comment: saying that the property does not exist

Comment: I have not had that happen to me before, what versions are you using? (or cocos2d and 3d?) there was some incompatible versions.

Comment: To fix it all I did was comment that section out, which is not usually a good idea, and then it worked. I am using cocos2d 2.1 and that cocos3d you gave me.

Comment: So yes, its not for 2.x yt, "Note: cocos3d is not yet compatible with cocos2d 2.x. Please use cocos2d 1.x." according to the site.